# iPhone how to disable sound notifications at work

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications, sound-volume

Let's say you are at the office 9-5, can you schedule the phone to be muted (mostly messaging, FB) during these hours and / or this location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done by scheduling **Do Not Disturb**.

Go into **Settings** → **Do Not Disturb** and *enable* `Scheduled` *from* 9 a.m. *To* 5 p.m.

Under **Allow Calls From** you may allow certain people to call you even while **Do Not Disturb** is active. Calls silenced by **Do Not Disturb** will go directly to voicemail.

At your discretion, you may also choose to `Always` silence notifications, or `Only while iPhone is locked`.

Emergency and Amber Alerts will still blare through **Do Not Disturb**. Those may only be silenced by toggling the hardware **Mute** switch, or by disabling them at the bottom of the **Notifications** menu.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Phong. Is there a way to set multiple schedules (like 9@5, 12@6am, etc.) ?

Comment: Unfortunately, not as of iOS 11. It is also not possible to geofence DND.

Comment: When is the iPhone is considered in locked state?

Comment: I’m sorry; I don’t understand what you mean by that.

Comment: when you say "Only while iPhone is locked", do you mean the lock screen?

Comment: Yes, the iPhone is locked when it’s on the lock screen or the screen is off.

Comment: i'm still looking for a solution that can support multiple schedules, but your reply answers the question the way it is phrased, so I'll accept your answer.